# Mapping a Volume in a docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to map a Volume to the docker image using -v "/Users//data:/data/"

```
> docker run -p 27017:27017 --name mongo2_001 -d mongo -v "/Users/<user>/data:/data"
6cf25618d...

> docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID IMAGE     COMMAND                  STATUS PORTS NAMES
6cf25618d..  mongo   "/usr/bin/mongod -v /"   Exited (1)                              mongoMG_001
```

It fails with the following error

```
> docker logs 6cf25618d..
2016-08-30T01:35:28.197+0000 F CONTROL  [main] Failed global
initialization: BadValue: The "verbose" option string cannot
contain any characters other than "v"
```

When ran with out "-v ..." seems to work properly.
Not sure what could be wrong.

PS: Dockerfile used to create the image used above

```
FROM       ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER Docker
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927
RUN echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu $(cat /etc/lsb-release | grep DISTRIB_CODENAME | cut -d= -f2)/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y mongodb-org
RUN mkdir -p /data/db
WORKDIR /data
EXPOSE 27017
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/mongod"]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order of "-v" parameter passed was incorrect.

Instead of going to docker command "-v" options it going to mongo container. Hence reorder the command as shown below

```
docker run -p 27018:27017 -v /Users/<user>/data:/data --name mongo2_001 -d mongo
```

On windows

```
docker run -p 27017:27017 -v /c/Users/<user>/data:/data --name mongo2_001 -d mongo
```

Comment: Still the same "2016-08-30T03:05:39.981+0000 F CONTROL  [main] Failed global initialization: BadValue: The "verbose" option string cannot contain any characters other than "v"". Wonder I am using mac & if I have some limitation on paths that can be used.

Comment: if you installed docker as instructed from docker it shouldn't be a problem because I do this all the time...

Comment: Fixed it by changing the order of the "-v ..." and putting it before "--name" options as shown "docker run -p 27018:27017 -v /Users/<user>/data:/data --name mongo2_001 -d mongo". But thanks for the info :)

Comment: did I get the best ans in that case? :D

Comment: @Vic that's your answer; your -v parameter was being passed to the mongo container (confusing it completely) instead of to the docker command. You should post that as the answer and accept it yourself, to clarify exactly what the solution was.

Comment: It works with this command "docker run -p 27017:27017 -v $HOME/docker/volumes/mongo/data:/data --name mongodb -d mongo" but what is the matter of ordering docker options? Can you explain this ?

Answer (score 0):

Mike Tung answer was not working for me. I was able to make it work with following command

```
docker run --name mongodb_win -v mongoWinData:/data/db -d -p 37017:27017 mongo
```